# Ошибка ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED при открытии файла

Tags: c++, winapi

Доброго времени суток. Суть вопроса такова:

В программе с помощью функции `WinAPI` открываю файл

```
HRESULT ReadFile(LPCWSTR name)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    DWORD   Error = 0;
    HANDLE  OResult= 0;

    // Open file
    OResult = CreateFile(name, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (OResult == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        Error = GetLastError();
    }
return hr;
}
```

И все вроде-бы хорошо - при запуске программы из проводника файл открывается, читается, но когда моя программа запускается через автозапуск (прописана в `"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"`) то `GetLastError()` возвращает код ошибки `5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)`.

Сейчас изучаю `Access Control Model` но пока безрезультатно.
Может кто сталкивался или знает подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем причина, куда копать?

ps: файл для открытия создан той же программой до перезагрузки, лежит в папке с экзешником. Другим процессом не открыт (вроде бы.. хотя как проверить?).

@Владимир Мартьянов: Если файла нет, возвращает ту-же ошибку.

Решено: отключением `UAC` в манифесте проекта. Иначе запуск программы из ветки `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run` происходит с ограничеными правами.

Comment: Что это за файл? Может при старте его (в эксклюзивном режиме) открывает какой-то другой процесс?

Comment: А если файла нет и на его создание тоже нет прав - не будет ли та же ошибка? А то у вас OPEN_ALWAYS как никак...